# When to use "and" in a noun phrase with multiple modifiers

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Is the phrase "my big blue eyes" correct?

If the words big and blue are describing eyes, shouldn't there be an "and" in-between the two?

When is it mandatory to use "and?"

Comment: I edited your question to say *phrase*.  "My big blue eyes" is not a complete sentence on its own.

Answer (score 1):

"My big blue eyes" **is correct**, because size adjectives ("big" in this case) must come before color adjectives ("blue" in this case).

"and" isn't frequently used when writing several adjectives, you don't need a word to link them, they must be written just one after the other. It could be used when writing **[coordinate adjectives](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000072.htm)**, but in general a "," (comma) is used to separate them, and the "and" is used just as a one of the rules needed to figure out if they are actually coordinate adjectives, so in that case you can put a comma between them. Examples:

> In addition, their breathtakingly cruel **and** callous actions also led to a tribute plaque.
>   Obama stands accused of giving stuffy **, (comma)** cliche-ridden graduation speeches.

As far as I know, there's not a formal definition to describe when it's mandatory.
But here are some cases where an "and" between adjectives is commonly used:

When using "to be" + **"both"** / **"at once"**:

> Salads are **both** tasty **and** delicious.
>
> Salads are at once *adj1*, *adj2*, *adj3* **and** *adj4*

When using **"such a"**:

> Have you ever seen such a big **and** thin pizza?

Comment: Does this mean I can write both "big blue eyes" and "big and blue eyes?"

Comment: This particular phrase using the "and" without a context would sound quite rare and even more when writting. Probably it's not strictly wrong, but without a context that worth the use of "and", for example, to emphatize, it would sound quite unnatural.